# How to remove User login box from public event registration?

Tags: civievent

I am creating a public event for my organization and is showing the User Login box on the left side. This is the box use to log in into CIVI so as long as attendee ignores it and use the form  there's no problem. But I want to remove it as some people have got confuse with it. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Hi Julio, it helps to add the used CMS and the version of CiviCRM to get better answers. But from your screenshot I assume you are using Drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is a Drupal question. The login of CiviCRM is handled by the CMS. Form the screenshot I assume it is Drupal. So the visibility of the login block must be configured in Drupal.
You find the configuration with the following URL

```
http://<servername>/admin/structure/block/manage/user/login/configure
```

Here you can disable the login box for event pages in the following way:
[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much.